# Transforming Data for Classification

Tags: machine-learning, data, data-cleaning, machine-learning-model

I have a dataset of the type:

[image]

Time_from_anchor is the time from when the diagnosis was made, if he had cancer. i.e patient 1 was diagnosed with cancer at 0. He had tests x and y at time -1 and tests x and z at time -3. OR it is the minimum time between last test and today if diagnosis was negative.

How would I create a new feature that accounts for both the time of different tests and the different types of events and their numeric values for each patient?

Comment: Your data is not clear. Could you post it in a better format, perhaps as a data frame? And also what exactly are you asking? You should clarify it as well.

Comment: i have updated the question now.